# Is there a type discrepancy that is causing this 'NoReverseMatch' in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

According to the Django docs, a NoReverseMatch happens when "a matching URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters supplied."

I am getting the following NoReverseMatch error.  My question is: why is the parameter supplied not being caught by the url?  Is it expecting a parameter of a different type?  I'm still not too comfortable with Django urls.

```
"Reverse for 'recall' with arguments '(<Unordered_Group: countries>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"
```

This question is revised from [Django NoReverseMatch url issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657922/django-noreversematch-url-issue/23658342#23658342) after suggestions were tried.

edited:

images/urls.py (project level)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^images/', include('images_app.urls', namespace="images_app")),
    url(r'^associate/', include('associate.urls', namespace="associate")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

associate/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^learn/', "associate.views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^recall/(?P<ordered_group>\w+)', 'associate.views.recall', name='recall'),
    url(r'^$', "associate.views.index", name='index'),
)
```

learn.html

```
<form action="{% url 'associate:recall' ordered_group %}" method="post">   ERROR CAUGHT 
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div>
        <label for="recall">enter as many members of {{ ordered_group }} as you can recall </label>
        <input type="text" id="recall" name="recall">
    </div>
    <div id="enter_button">
        <input type="submit" value="enter" name="enter" />
    </div>
    <div id="done_button">
        <input type="submit" value="done" name="done" />
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def recall(request, ordered_group):
  ...


def learn(request):
... 
ordered_group = ordered_groups[index]

 return render(request, 'associate/learn.html', {'dataset':model, 'ordered_group':ordered_group})
```

Comment: Is this the `urls.py` of your app that is included into the the project-level `urls.py`? If yes, show the project-level `urls.py` contents. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe  Just edited it in, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, your URL pattern is expecting a regex which matches `[\w]+` which is one or more wordcharacters.

```
recall/(?P<ordered_group>\w+)
```

But it actually got an object.

A better way of doing this would be to send the id of the ordered group object (or any other unique identifier), and querying for that object in the view again.

Note that if you go with the id, URL pattern regex would be

```
recall/(?P<ordered_group>\d+)
```

and the view:

```
def recall(request, ordered_group):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Unordered_Group, id=ordered_group)
    #rest of the code..
```